# Question on function properties

Tags: functions

I've come across a question that I'm not too sure how to answer. If someone could explain the answer to this, I would be most grateful.

If $f(x)$ is a function defined for all real numbers, then for all $x$,
    $f(x^2 + 3x) = f(x^2) + f(3x)$.

Is this statement true or false?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question about the function your being asked?

Comment: This doesn't make sense without more information. What is the context here? Where did you encounter this statement? This is certainly not a property of an arbitrary real variable function.

Comment: Oh sorry - its a true or false question.

Comment: @manthanomen So its false then? Could explain why?

Comment: Are you told anything more about the function?

Comment: @theGreatWhatever I think $f(x) = a.x $ will do ,where $a \in \mathbb{R} $ or in $\mathbb{C}$ as you have not specified the codomain of $f$.

Comment: @BAYMAX Any linear function like $f(x) = ax$ will always have the property mentioned in the question.

Comment: @manthanomen    yes true . if the question asks for all functions then it would be false  and if it asks for if there exists a function with the above property then it will be true as there exists linear function with the above property.

Comment: @theGreatWhatever You haven't told us if $f$ must have any specific properties. Assuming it's just an arbitrary function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, define $f$ by $f(1) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 1$. Then $f(1^2 + 3(1)) = f(4) = 0$ but $f(1^2) + f(3(1)) = 1 + 0 = 1$.

Comment: @BAYMAX As stated in the question (the only requirement for $f$ is that the domain is $\mathbb R$), the claim is false. theGreatWhatever asks whether the statement is true or false, not whether there exists such a function.

Comment: @manthanomen ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is *any* real-valued function, then the statement is false. For example the constant function $f(x)=1$ makes the equation equivalent to $1=1+1$ for any $x$.

However, if a function's codomain is $\{0\}$ then yes, for all $x$ the equation is satisfied as $0=0+0$, and the statement is true.

Comment: manthanomen answered first, but yours is comprehensive. Thanks!